# Locating href in a using a tag using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to find `href` in `a` tag using puppeteer, I have tried several methods but none could help me.

`<a class="styles__StyledLink-sc-l6elh8-0 ekTmzq Asset--anchor" href="/foo1/foo2/foo3"></a>` is the exact `a` im trying to use to cooperate with my program.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const a = document.querySelector('a.styles__StyledLink-sc-l6elh8-0..ekTmzq.Asset--anchor')
  .getAttribute('href');
});
```